# Creating a visible frame in Java?

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

class apples{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // creating black background
    JFrame start = new JFrame("TatteredLands");
    start.getContentPane().setVisible(true);
    start.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

}
```

}

Is it because, I have to set a size of the frame or something that this doesn't work?

Comment: please set the visibility of your frame with `.setVisible(true);`

Comment: @Rugal Please refrain from answering questions in the comments.

Comment: @LeeAllan is there any regulation on this?

Comment: If by regulation you mean advice and the comment areas default text being 'Avoid answering questions in comments' then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically, need to make sure you are setting the frame itself visible, as it is `false` by default.

`JFrame` is basically just a special type of `Component`, so just like you would make a `Component` visible, so should the frame...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // creating black background
            JFrame start = new JFrame("TatteredLands");
            start.getContentPane().setVisible(true);
            start.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
            start.pack();
            start.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            start.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Should also take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and make sure you are starting you UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

I would also suggest taking some time to read through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the content pane visible, set the frame visible. The content frame is nothing without the actual frame.

```
start.setVisible(true);
```

Also, it is preferred not to set the size of the frame. Instead call `start.pack()` and that will pack the frame to respect the preferred sizes of all components added to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if you're new to Java that you download an IDE such as Eclipse, they let you see what methods objects contain, do I have to explain how much trouble that will save?
The content pane of a JFrame is what is inside it, usually referred to as the 'container', so you are calling `setVisible()` on the wrong object. You want `start.setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the `JFrame` visible true like `start.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    JFrame start = new JFrame("TatteredLands");
    start.setVisible(true);
    start.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    // add other initialization operations here...
```